# Flutter: Change text colour of a widget, when a button is pressed

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 Pieces of text, which come from an API call, one in German, one translated in English, they are fed as parameters into a Basic Template, which holds custom styling of the Text. The second Text, the translation is the same colour as the background and when the Reveal button is pressed, I would like the colour to become white (visible). An image for clarity:[image]

How would I change the colour of the second text, I am unsure due to feeding the data through the custom made templates (See code below). **Any point in the right direction appreciated.**

**Main Class**

```
class MistakesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  String username;
  MistakesScreen({this.username});

  @override
  _MistakesScreenState createState() => _MistakesScreenState();
}

class _MistakesScreenState extends State<MistakesScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Hello ${widget.username}"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchGermanPhrases(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
                return Text('Connection State None');
              case ConnectionState.active:
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              case ConnectionState.done:
                var gname = snapshot.data['gname'].toString();
                var ename = snapshot.data['ename'].toString();
                return BasicExerciseTemplate(textOne: gname, textTwo: ename);
              default:
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Templates and Button Code:**

```
class BasicTextTemplate extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final Color colour;
  BasicTextTemplate({this.text, this.colour});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: colour,
              fontSize: 30,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        width: 350,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.green.shade800,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BasicExerciseTemplate extends StatelessWidget {
  final String textOne;
  final String textTwo;
  BasicExerciseTemplate({this.textOne, this.textTwo});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: BasicTextTemplate(text: textOne, colour: Colors.white),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child:
                BasicTextTemplate(text: textTwo, colour: Colors.green.shade800),
          ),
          RevealButton()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RevealButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String textOne;
  final String textTwo;
  RevealButton({this.textOne, this.textTwo});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: FlatButton(
        child: Text('Reveal'),
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        onPressed: () {
          print('Reveal Pressed');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
isReveal = false;

onPressed: () {
 setState(() {
   IsReveal = true
 });
},

BasicTextTemplate(text: textTwo, colour:!isReveal ? Colors.green.shade800:Colors.white);
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you are trying, I recommend you to use the `Visibility` widget. It controls whether the given child is visible or not. I think it'll be much easier.

For instance:

```
      Visibility(
        visible: myBoolean,
        child: Text(
          "Die Deutschen sind sehr nett",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
      ),
```

Simply use a function where you change the value of your boolean and trigger the `setState` method. That way you'll be able to hide or show your texts depending on a condition. For more info, see:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html

Comment: This also works! Thanks I didn't know this Widget existed will now begin using.

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could contribute to your Flutter knowledge ;)